# Increase performance for checking file delimiters

Tags: performance, powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

After spending some time looking for the most clearcut way to check if the body of a file has the same amount of delimiters as the header I came up with this code:

```
Param #user enters the directory path and delimiter they are checking for
(
    [string]$source,
    [string]$delim
)

#try {
$lineNum = 1
$thisOK = 0
$badLine = 0
$noDelim = 0
$archive = ("*archive*","*Archive*","*ARCHIVE*");

foreach ($files in Get-ChildItem $source -Exclude $archive) #folder directory may have sub folders, as a temp workaround just made sure to exclude any folder with archive
{
    $read2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($files.FullName)
    $DataLine = (Get-Content $files.FullName)[0]
    $validCount = ([char[]]$DataLine -eq $delim).count #count of delimeters in the header
    $lineNum = 1 #used to write to host which line is bad in file
    $thisOK = 0 #used for if condition to let the host know that the file has delimeters that line up with header
    $badLine = 0 #used so the write-host doesnt meet the if condition and write the file is ok after throwing an error

    while (!$read2.EndOfStream)
    {
        $line = $read2.ReadLine()
        $total = $line.Split($delim).Length - 1;

        if ($total -eq $validCount)
        {
            $thisOK = 1
        }
        elseif ($total -ne $validCount)
        {
            Write-Output "Error on line $lineNum for file $files. Line number $lineNum has $total delimeters and the header has $validCount"
            $thisOK = 0
            $badLine = 1
            break; #break or else it will repeat each line that is bad
        }
        $lineNum++
    }
    if ($thisOK = 1 -and $badLine -eq 0 -and $validCount -ne 0)
    {
        Write-Output "$files is ok"
    }
    if ($validCount -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Output "$files does not contain entered delimeter: $delim"
    }
    $read2.Close()
    $read2.Dispose()
} #end foreach loop
#} catch {
#    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
#    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
#}
```

It works for what I have tested so far. However, when it comes to larger files, it takes considerably longer.  I was wondering what I can do or change for this code to make it process these text/CSV files more quickly?

Also, my `try..catch` statements are commented out since the script doesn't seem to run when I include them - no error just enters a new command line. As a thought I was looking to incorporate a simple GUI for other users to double check.

Sample file:

```
HeaderA|HeaderB|HeaderC|HeaderD          //header line
DataLnA|DataLnBBDataLnC|DataLnD|DataLnE  //bad line
DataLnA|DataLnB|DataLnC|DataLnD|         //bad line
DataLnA|DataLnB|DataLnC|DataLnD          //good line
```

Now that I look at it, I guess there could be an issue where there are the correct amount if delimeters but the columns mismatch like this:

```
HeaderA|HeaderB|HeaderC|HeaderD
DataLnA|DataLnBDataLnC|DataLnD|
```

Comment: A sample of the files with their "delimiters" would help clarify what you're asking, presently I am having difficulty understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It is considered good question asking etiquette on SO to _fully_ indent your code. It makes it more readable to potential answerers. In general it's highly recommended to read the Help Section info on how to write a good question.

Comment: You already have a `StreamReader`. Why are you using `Get-Content` for reading the first line?

Comment: Sorry, the delimiters are characters like, "|" or ",". Basically, we receive files where the header has the right amount of delimiters but the actually body of the file may be missing some and causing loading issues when running the ETL

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I was using it to get the count of delimiters in the header line to compare to the rest of the file.

Comment: @Kev added example file to main question

Comment: And your stream reader can't read the header line, because ...?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I didn't realize I could use the '-First 1' to pick the header line

Comment: Your **`System.IO.StreamReader`** can't read the header line, because ...?

Comment: I knew that it could, I just didnt know how to pull the first line then do a count on it. @AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem that I see is that you are reading the file *twice* -- once with the call to `Get-Content`, which reads the entire file into memory, and a second time with your `while` loop.  You can double the speed of your process by replacing this line:

```
$DataLine = (Get-Content $files.FullName)[0]    #inefficient
```

with this:

```
$DataLine = Get-Content $files.FullName -First 1   #efficient
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was too lazy when it came to writing that part. It worked so i will stick with that.

Comment: Glad to have helped!